# How to replace image using button in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Image layout :

[image: image layout]

How can I replace image using button next and previous in android studio ?

Example : image1 (next) image2  to image3

and

image3 (previous) image2 (previous) image1

Comment: please show your stuff

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a list of images like `List<String> imageNames` and fill them with image id of your images which copied in `drawable` folder.

Use `int id = getResources().getIdentifier("image1", "drawable", context.getPackageName());` to get the `id` of an image and fill the list with them.

Then write this code to listen to button click:

```
Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
int index = 0;
btnNext .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       if(index <= imageNames.size()) {
           mImageView.setImageResource(imageNames.get(index));
           index++;
       }
    }
});
```

And do the same for `btnPrev`.

Comment: how do you mean, the red circle?

Comment: how do you mean, the red circle? img :https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Q6dBA_9OQVE/WAz_iN2qZoI/AAAAAAAAAms/cd8JwAVhe9Aal_Q9FzVfkXNGhBoVUHDAACLcB/s320/image.png IMG :https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-CK6fwCyHya4/WAz_iuaOuZI/AAAAAAAAAmw/GwuCXdDgh3wroNMOXUo75h2x6cv6lrCkQCLcB/s320/string.png

Comment: you should use ``R.drawable.yourimage``, put your img in drawable folder